Conditional distribution on the linear inequality
A paper I am reading states the following Lemma as a well-known formula, but I can not find this formula anywhere else nor a complete proof of the lemma. I am also wondering if this lemma or something similar holds in the case $z$ is not normally distributed but still has mean $0$ and variance $v^2$. Any help is appreciated!
Lemma:
Let $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with i.i.d. $\mathbf{N}(0,v^2)$ entries and let $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a linear
operator with full row rank. Then for any constant vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ the distribution of $z $ conditioned
on $Dz = b$ satisfies:
$$z|_{Dz=b}
\overset{d}{=} D^\top(DD^\top)^{-1}b + P_{\{Dz=0\}}(\tilde{z})$$
where $P_{\{Dz=0\}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\{Dz = 0\}$ and $\tilde{z}$ is a random vector of
i.i.d. $\mathbf{N}(0, v^2)$. Moreover, $D^\top(DD^\top)^{-1}b = arg min_z(||Z||^2 | Dz = b)$.

There's something funny going on here. What is "the subspace ${ Dz = 0 }$"? I do not see how that "$z$" can be the same random "$z$" introduced earlier in the question. Perhaps you meant "the subspace ${ y \in \mathbb{R}^n : Dy = 0 }$". If so, I can prove the lemma.

This proof takes the statement "the subspace $\{ Dz = 0\}$" to mean "the subspace $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n : Dy = 0\}$" and the notation is adjusted to reflect that.
First, I note that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$P_{\{Dy = 0\}}(x) = x - D^\top (D D^\top)^{-1} D x$$
This is derived by solving $P_{\{Dy = 0\}}(x) = \underset{y}{\arg \min} \frac{1}{2} \lVert x - y \rVert_2^2$ subject to $Dy = 0$. Then observe
$$D z|_{Dz = b} \overset{\text{d}}{=} b$$
and
$$DP_{\{Dy = 0 \}}(\tilde{z}) \overset{\text{d}}{=} 0$$
so
$$D z|_{Dz = b} \overset{\text{d}}{=} DD^\top (DD^\top)^{-1} b + DP_{\{Dy = 0 \}}(\tilde{z})$$
which implies
$$z|_{Dz = b} \overset{\text{d}}{=} D^\top (DD^\top)^{-1} b + P_{\{Dy = 0 \}}(\tilde{z})$$
